# Snake Game. How to make the snake lose a piece of tail when eating rotten apples?

Tags: java, linked-list

I already added to the game the apples and added a feature that makes the apples get rotten after certain steps of the snake. But I want the snake to lose a piece of tail when eating a rotten apple.

I already have the method that adds a piece of tail every time the snake eats. I just need some help. I've tried using pollLast() and removeLast() but I can't figure it out.

```java
*package Game.Entities.Dynamic;
import Main.Handler;
import Resources.Images;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import Display.DisplayScreen;
import Game.GameStates.State;
/**
 * Created by AlexVR on 7/2/2018.
 */
public class Player {
    public int lenght;
    public boolean justAte;
    private Handler handler;
    public int xCoord;
    public int yCoord;
    public int score;
    public int steps;
    public int moveCounter;
    public String direction;
    private String highscore;
    private Color playerColor;
    private Color appleColor;
    private Color rottenAppleColor;
    private int speedAdjust;
    private Tail tail;
    private String eatSoundEffect;
    private String deathSoundEffect;
    private boolean soundLoop;

    public Player(Handler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
        xCoord = 0;
        yCoord = 0;
        score = 0;
        steps = 0;
        highscore = this.getHighScore();
        moveCounter = 0;
        direction= "Right";
        justAte = false;
        lenght= 1;
        playerColor = Color.green;
        appleColor = Color.red;
        rottenAppleColor = Color.black;
        speedAdjust = 20;
        eatSoundEffect = "res/music/bite.wav";
        deathSoundEffect = "res/music/sound-frogger-dead.wav";
        soundLoop = true;

    }
    public void tick(){
        moveCounter += 2;
        if(moveCounter>=speedAdjust) {
            checkCollisionAndMove();
            checkSteps();
            moveCounter=0;
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP) || handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_W)){
            direction="Up";
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) || handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_S)){
            direction="Down";
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) || handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_A)){
            direction="Left";
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) || handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_D)){
            direction="Right";
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS)){
            speedAdjust-=2;
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS)){
            speedAdjust+=2;
        }
        if(handler.getKeyManager().keyJustPressed(KeyEvent.VK_N)) {
            this.setJustAte(false);
            EatAndAddTail(); 
        }   
    }
    public void checkCollisionAndMove(){
        handler.getWorld().playerLocation[xCoord][yCoord]=false;
        int x = xCoord;
        int y = yCoord;
        steps++;
        switch (direction){
            case "Left":
                if(xCoord==0){
                    xCoord = handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1;
                }else{
                    xCoord--;
                }
                break;
            case "Right":
                if(xCoord==handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1){
                    xCoord = 0;
                }else{
                    xCoord++;
                }
                break;
            case "Up":
                if(yCoord==0){
                    yCoord = handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1;
                }else{
                    yCoord--;
                }
                break;
            case "Down":
                if(yCoord==handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1){
                    yCoord = 0;
                }else{
                    yCoord++;
                }
                break;
        }

        handler.getWorld().playerLocation[xCoord][yCoord]=true;

        if (handler.getWorld().body.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < handler.getWorld().body.size(); i++){
                //Kill player when collides with itself
                if(xCoord == handler.getWorld().body.get(i).x && yCoord == handler.getWorld().body.get(i).y) {
                    kill();
                } 
            }
        }

        if(handler.getWorld().appleLocation[xCoord][yCoord]){
            this.setJustAte(true);
            EatAndAddTail();
        }

        //Displays the score on the bottom as soon as the game starts and gets updated whenever the snake eats a dot
        if((xCoord > 0 || yCoord > 0) || justAte==true){
            DisplayScreen.setMessage(String.format("Current Score: %d; %s", score, highscore)); 
        }
        if(!handler.getWorld().body.isEmpty()) {
            handler.getWorld().playerLocation[handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x][handler.getWorld().body.getLast().y] = false;
            handler.getWorld().body.removeLast();
            handler.getWorld().body.addFirst(new Tail(x, y,handler));
        }

        System.out.println(steps);
    }

    //If the snake has made 60 or more steps then the apple becomes rotten.
    public void checkSteps() {
        if (steps >= 80) {
            handler.getWorld().apple.setIsGood(false);
        }
    }
    public void render(Graphics g,Boolean[][] playeLocation){
        //Changes color of the snake
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount; j++) {
                g.setColor(playerColor);
                if(playeLocation[i][j]||handler.getWorld().appleLocation[i][j]){
                    g.fillRect((i*handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize),
                            (j*handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize),
                            handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize,
                            handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize);
                }
            }
        }

        //Changes the color of the apple
        for (int i = 0; i < handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount; j++) {
                if (handler.getWorld().apple.isGood) {
                g.setColor(appleColor);
                }
                else {
                    g.setColor(rottenAppleColor);
                }
                if(handler.getWorld().appleLocation[i][j]){
                        g.fillRect((i*handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize),
                                (j*handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize),
                                handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize,
                                handler.getWorld().GridPixelsize);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void EatAndAddTail(){
        lenght++;
        //Kills the snake if it eats a rotten apple and has no tail.
        if(justAte == true && handler.getWorld().apple.isGood == false && score == 0){
             kill(); 
        }
        else if (justAte == true) {
            this.setSteps(0);
            if (handler.getWorld().apple.isGood) {
                //Score formula when eating a good apple.
                score += Math.sqrt(2*score + 1);
                //Increases the speed of the snake everytime it eats a dot.
                speedAdjust -= 5;
            }
            else if (handler.getWorld().apple.isGood == false) {
                //Score formula when eating a rotten apple.
                score -= Math.sqrt(2*score + 1);
            }
            handler.getGame().playAudio(eatSoundEffect, false);
            handler.getWorld().appleLocation[xCoord][yCoord]=false;
            handler.getWorld().appleOnBoard=false;
            switch (direction){
            case "Left":
                if(handler.getWorld().body.isEmpty()){
                    if(this.xCoord!=handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1){
                        tail = new Tail(this.xCoord+1,this.yCoord,handler);
                    }
                    else {
                        if(this.yCoord!=0){
                            tail = new Tail(this.xCoord,this.yCoord-1,handler);
                        }
                        else{
                            tail =new Tail(this.xCoord,this.yCoord+1,handler);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x!=handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1){
                        tail=new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x+1,this.yCoord,handler);
                    }
                    else {
                        if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().y!=0){
                            tail=new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x,this.yCoord-1,handler);
                        }
                        else {
                            tail=new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x,this.yCoord+1,handler);
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "Right":
                if(handler.getWorld().body.isEmpty()){
                    if(this.xCoord!=0){
                        tail=new Tail(this.xCoord-1,this.yCoord,handler);
                    }
                    else {
                        if(this.yCoord!=0){
                            tail=new Tail(this.xCoord,this.yCoord-1,handler);
                        }
                        else {
                            tail=new Tail(this.xCoord,this.yCoord+1,handler);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x!=0){
                        tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x-1,this.yCoord,handler));
                    }
                    else {
                        if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().y!=0){
                            tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x,this.yCoord-1,handler));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x,this.yCoord+1,handler));
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "Up":
                if(handler.getWorld().body.isEmpty()){
                    if(this.yCoord!=handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1){
                        tail=(new Tail(this.xCoord,this.yCoord+1,handler));
                    }
                    else {
                        if(this.xCoord!=0){
                            tail=(new Tail(this.xCoord-1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tail=(new Tail(this.xCoord+1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    if (handler.getWorld().body.getLast().y!=handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount-1){
                        tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x,this.yCoord+1,handler));
                    } 
                    else {
                        if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x!=0){
                            tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x-1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                        else{
                            tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x+1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            case "Down":
                if(handler.getWorld().body.isEmpty()){
                    if(this.yCoord!=0){
                        tail=(new Tail(this.xCoord,this.yCoord-1,handler));
                    }
                    else{
                        if(this.xCoord!=0){
                            tail=(new Tail(this.xCoord-1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                        else{
                            tail=(new Tail(this.xCoord+1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().y!=0){
                        tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x,this.yCoord-1,handler));
                    }
                    else{
                        if(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x!=0){
                            tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x-1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                        else{
                            tail=(new Tail(handler.getWorld().body.getLast().x+1,this.yCoord,handler));
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

            handler.getWorld().body.addLast(tail);
            handler.getWorld().playerLocation[tail.x][tail.y] = true;
        }
        else{
            handler.getWorld().body.addLast(new Tail(xCoord, yCoord, handler));
        }
    }
    public void kill(){
        lenght = 0;
        handler.getGame().stopMainAudio();
        handler.getGame().playAudio(deathSoundEffect, false);

        for (int i = 0; i < handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < handler.getWorld().GridWidthHeightPixelCount; j++) {
                handler.getWorld().playerLocation[i][j]=false;
                State.setState(handler.getGame().gameOverState); 
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean isJustAte() {
        return justAte;
    }
    public void setJustAte(boolean justAte) {
        this.justAte = justAte;
    }
}*
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm not misunderstanding your code, then it seems as though you're creating a new tail for everytime the snake eats an apple.

At the top of your `EatAndAddTail()` method you're doing `lenght++` perhaps you shouldn't have that at the very top, since it's effectively adding another segment, which is the opposite of what you want to do. Maybe having a method where you check that the length is equal to the amount of segments, after an apple is eaten, and adjust size accordingly. Tracking size can also be easily done. Something like this,

```
if (justAte == true && handler.getWorld().apple.isGood == false){
lenght--;
check(lenght);
size--;
}

else if (justAte == true){
lenght++;
check(lenght);
size++;
}

private void check (int l){
    if (lenght != size){
         if (lenght > size)
         {
             removeTail();
         }
         else
         {  
             addTail();
         }
     }
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense. Though you might have to add a removeTail() and an addTail() method.